# Azure Data Factory Data Flow using Cached Lookup into select task

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use Data Flow Cached Lookups to implement a dynamic columns mapping from from a SQL source to a SQL destination. The idea is to persists a map on a metadata table, read as source into the Data Flow and store as Cached Lookup. It looks like this:

[image]

(The Key Columns is set to sourceField)

Now we just need to use this map into a Rule Based Mapping into a Select transform in order to select mapped only columns and apply the target naming. The expression is the following:

[image]

This configuration will result in a runtime error on the Select task:

[image]

Do you have any idea why? The error message is not helpful.

Edit: below the full script definition

```
parameters{
    sourceSchema as string ("dbo"),
    sourceTable as string ("RiepilogoSocieta")
}
source(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    inferDriftedColumnTypes: true,
    isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',
    format: 'table') ~> DatabookSource
source(output(
        {_id} as integer,
        sourceSchema as string,
        sourceTable as string,
        sourceField as string,
        targetField as string,
        targetType as string,
        targetSchema as string,
        targetTable as string
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',
    format: 'table') ~> Objmetadata
DatabookSource select(mapColumn(
        each(match(!isNull(CacheFieldsMap#lookup(name).targetField)),
            CacheFieldsMap#lookup($$).targetField = $$)
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> MapColumns
Objmetadata filter(sourceSchema == $sourceSchema && sourceTable == $sourceTable) ~> FilterForSourceTable
FilterForSourceTable select(mapColumn(
        sourceField,
        targetField
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> SelectFieldsMap
MapColumns derive({_createdAt} = currentTimestamp(),
        {_updatedAt} = currentTimestamp()) ~> AddMetaColums
AddMetaColums sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    deletable:false,
    insertable:true,
    updateable:false,
    upsertable:false,
    truncate:true,
    format: 'table',
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,
    errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> AnalyticsSink
SelectFieldsMap sink(skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,
    keys:['sourceField'],
    store: 'cache',
    format: 'inline',
    output: false,
    saveOrder: 1) ~> CacheFieldsMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Post the DSL script(click on script button). I can't make out what patterns $$ is mapping to. Make sure that is datatype compatible and not passing integer types for string parameters to lookup.

Comment: Thanks Kiran, just updated my post with the script definition.

Comment: It is not supported currently but it is in the immediate backlog. Until then you should split this as a dataflow activity(or lookup activity) followed by a dataflow activity and pass in this information as an array to the second dataflow.

Comment: This feature should be available in a couple of weeks